# How to display a directive in response to an error from any controller in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have many calls to `$http` in my app.  I want to create a global error modal popup to handle these errors (where I can pass in information depending on what the error was).

To do this I am making a `modal` directive.

The code for the directive looks like this:

```
angular.module('nightwalkerApp')        
  .directive('siteModal', () => {      
    return {               
      restrict: 'E',             
      templateUrl: 'partials/modal.html' 
    }                     
  })
```

And my template looks like this:

```
<div id="modal" ng-show="showModal">      
  <button ng-click="hideModal()">X</button>     
  <p class="modal-info">Some example words</p>  
  <p class="modal-footer">{{info}}</p>         
</div>
```

As you can see, I want to pass in some information when I display that modal window.  Originally I had `controller: ModalCtl` as a parameter  to the directive, (to enable the `hideModal` function etc.) but what happens is that I want to be able to set things such as `{{info}}` from all of my other controllers.

I can't just inject the `ModalCtl` into other controllers and start calling functions that way, but if I make some sort of error handling service or factory then I don't know how I can create `$scope` specific functionality such as `ng-click="hideModal"` because those rely on a controller.

For example, I would like to use a controller that looks like this:

angular.module('nightwalkerApp')
  .controller('ErrorCtl', function ($scope) => {

```
const info = document.querySelector('#modal.modal-info')                                                                                                                                                                            
const footer = document.querySelector('#modal.modal-footer')                                                                                                                                                                        
const defaultFooter = 'Please contact help@example.com'                                                                                                                                                                             
$scope.hideModal = function () {
  // Hide modal etc.
}                                                                                                                                                                                                             
function displayError (err, optionalInfo) {

  if (optionalInfo) {                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    info.textContent = optionalInfo                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    footer.textContent = defaultFooter                                                                                                                                                                                              
  } else if (err.status >= 500) {                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    info.textContent = 'We are sorry but our services are currently unavailable'                                                                                                                                                    
    footer.textContent = 'Please check back soon'                                                                                                                                                                                   
  } else {                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    info.textContent = err.message                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    info.textContent = 'Please examine your request or contact help@example.com'                                                                                                                                                    
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

})

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: Please show more code - how u use current directive

Comment: @pawlakppp Thanks updated.

Comment: Events would be a good solution. Add your directive to your markup somewhere, it will listen to an event them simply emit that event should you have an error. Your controllers don't need to know anything about what's listening to that event.

Comment: Your current solution is not very 'angular'. I think you should read about isolating directive scope and passing parameteres: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive